# substitution cipher technique where every letter is replaced with one 7 letters down the alphabetic line

Tags: java

I'm using substitution cipher technique where every letter is replaced with one 7 letters down the alphabetic line.If space occurs between the words of input, it must occur in output also.

```
class Cipher 
{ 
    public static StringBuffer encrypt(String text, int s) 
    { 
        StringBuffer result= new StringBuffer(); 
        for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) 
        { 
            if (Character.isUpperCase(text.charAt(i))) 
            { 
                char ch = (char)(((int)text.charAt(i)+s));
                result.append(ch); 
            } 
            else
            { 
                char ch = (char)(((int)text.charAt(i)+s)); 
                result.append(ch); 
            } 
        } 
        return result; 
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String text = "zhcl dhaly"; 
        int s = -7; 
        System.out.println("Text : " + text); 
        System.out.println("Cipher: " + encrypt(text, s)); 
    } 
}
```

It shows the correct output as harini.But if i give  "Zhcldhaly" it prints "sa\e]aZer".But the correct output is "Savewater".

Comment: Please note: I saw you enhanced your question. So I did in my answer. But please note that you should not change the content repeatedly. You ask one question, you accept the helpful answer. And if you have another problem, you should rather ask a new question! Beyond that, your question is still unclear (please read [mcve]). And I would appreciate a bit of feedback on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the modulus to wrap around any character which, when shifted, would exceed the letter `z`:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
int s = 7;
String text = "Zhcldhaly";
for (int i=0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char chr = text.charAt(i);
    if (chr == ' ') {
        result.append(" ");
    }
    else if (Character.isUpperCase(chr)) {
        char ch = (char)('A' + (chr - 'A' - s + 26) % 26);
        result.append(ch);
    }
    else {
        char ch = (char)('a' + (chr - 'a' - s + 26) % 26);
        result.append(ch);
    }
}

System.out.println(result);
```

This outputs:

```
Savewater
```

Comment: Your code works correctly.But i'm trying is to replace every letter with 7 letters down the alphabetic line.

Comment: @Harini Then set `s = 7` in my script above.

Comment: If i set 7 then it prints the letter front to 7.but i want 7 letters down the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are complaining about `sa\e]aZer`, or to be precise: there is no space in there, which isn't what your assignment sways.

Thing is:

```
 if (Character.isUpperCase(text.charAt(i)))
```

that only checks if the char is Uppercase. It doesn't check if the char is a space.

It is pretty simple: you need an if statement that says: `if space, then append space else "translate"`.

Also note: that if statement in your current code is pointless. When you carefully look at the "then" and the "else" case, you will find that they are **identical**.

So, long story short: carefully look at *what kind of if* statement you need, and change your code accordingly. It might also be very helpful for you to carefully study the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table to better understand what kind of output to expect for your input characters.

Beyond that: you should understand that there is a difference between decryption and encryption! When you try to get back the original text you have to **reverse** the operation! When you subtract 7 for encryption, then you need to **add** 7 to decrypt. You can't decrypt an encrypted word using the *encrypt* method!